# ERROR: Report handler Chef::Handler::AuditReport raised #<ArgumentError: comparison of Float with String failed>

Tags: chef-infra

I am running audit cookbook for rhel8 server . Desired profiles are available in automate server . However chef-client ends with below error :

Running handlers:

```
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: Report handler Chef::Handler::AuditReport raised #<ArgumentError: comparison of Float with String failed>
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/audit/libraries/helper.rb:95:in `>'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/audit/libraries/helper.rb:95:in `profile_overdue_to_run?'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/audit/libraries/helper.rb:106:in `check_interval_settings'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/audit/files/default/handler/audit_report.rb:69:in `report'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.10.19/lib/chef/handler.rb:256:in `run_report_unsafe'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/audit/files/default/handler/audit_report.rb:100:in `run_report_safely'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.10.19/lib/chef/handler.rb:123:in `block in run_report_handlers'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.10.19/lib/chef/handler.rb:121:in `each'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.10.19/lib/chef/handler.rb:121:in `run_report_handlers'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.10.19/lib/chef/handler.rb:133:in `block in <class:Handler>'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.10.19/lib/chef/client.rb:426:in `block in run_completed_successfully'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.10.19/lib/chef/client.rb:425:in `each'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.10.19/lib/chef/client.rb:425:in `run_completed_successfully'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.10.19/lib/chef/client.rb:292:in `run'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.10.19/lib/chef/application.rb:320:in `run_with_graceful_exit_option'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.10.19/lib/chef/application.rb:296:in `block in run_chef_client'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.10.19/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:42:in `with_server_connectivity'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.10.19/lib/chef/application.rb:279:in `run_chef_client'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.10.19/lib/chef/application/base.rb:330:in `run_application'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.10.19/lib/chef/application.rb:68:in `run'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-bin-15.10.19/bin/chef-client:25:in `<top (required)>'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /usr/bin/chef-client:174:in `load'
[2021-01-05T11:08:56+01:00] ERROR: /usr/bin/chef-client:174:in `<main>'
  - Chef::Handler::AuditReport
Running handlers complete
Chef Infra Client finished, 6/536 resources updated in 36 seconds
```

audit cookbook version : 9.4.0
chef version: 15

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

What interval settings you have configured? Recommend to run

```
chef-client -l debug
```

I had a similar issue and the problem was that the interval time was set within quotes "1440" when displaying the debug logs it was showing the below:

```
[2021-02-11T10:28:16+00:00] DEBUG: Auditing this machine every 144014401440144014401440144014401440144014401440144014401440144014401440144014401440144014401440144014401440144014401440144014401440144014401440144014401440144014401440144014401440144014401440144014401440144014401440144014401440144014401440 seconds
```

After setting the interval without the Double quotes it was working fine.

I guess by the lack of answers this has been fixed already but posting for anyone having the same issue.